# Unable to open input file in Verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, input, testbench

I'm having trouble running my Verilog code.

Here is my code:

```
module hello(A,B);
input A;
output B;

assign B = A;  
endmodule
```

And here is my testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns
`include "hello.v"
    
module hello_tb;

reg A;
wire B;

hello uut(A, B);

initial begin     
    $dumfile("hello_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvar(0, hello_tb);

    A = 20;
    #20;

    A = -1;
    #20;

    A = 0;
    #20;

    $display("Test complete");
end

endmodule
```

These are the commands I'm running on my terminal:

`iverilog -o hello_tb.vvp hello_tb.v`

`vvp hello_tb.vvp`

And that's the error I'm getting:

`hello_tb.vvp: Unable to open input file.`

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your testbench file.

I get different error messages from you, but it is likely that I am running a different version of `iverilog`.  It's too bad you don't get a more specific error message.  Here are the errors I get:

```
iverilog -o hello_tb.vvp hello_tb.v
vvp hello_tb.vvp
hello_tb.v:13: Error: System task/function $dumfile() is not defined by any module.
hello_tb.v:14: Error: System task/function $dumpvar() is not defined by any module.
hello_tb.vvp: Program not runnable, 2 errors.
```

To fix those errors, change the testbench lines to:

```
$dumpfile("hello_tb.vcd");
$dumpvars(0, hello_tb);
```

That works for me.

It is important to note that both of the Verilog source code files (`hello_tb.v` and `hello.v`) are in the current directory when I run the `iverilog` command.

---

It is also unusual to assign values like 20 and -1 to a 1-bit signal (`A`) in the testbench.